# Find Customers With 4 Consecutive Years of Giving (Including Gaps)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, gaps-and-islands

I have a table similar to below:

```
+------------+-----------+
| CustomerID | OrderYear |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |      2012 |
|          1 |      2013 |
|          1 |      2014 |
|          1 |      2017 |
|          1 |      2018 |
|          2 |      2012 |
|          2 |      2013 |
|          2 |      2014 |
|          2 |      2015 |
|          2 |      2017 |
+------------+-----------+
```

How would I identify which CustomerIDs have 4 consecutive years of giving? (In the above, only customer 2.) As you can see, some records will have gaps in order years.

I started down the row of trying to utilize some combination of `ROW_NUMBER`/`LAG`/`LEAD` with no luck to this point.

Very paired down/modified attempt...

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT T.ConstituentLookupID,
       T.FISCALYEAR,
       COUNT(T.FISCALYEAR) OVER (PARTITION BY T.ConstituentLookupID) AS 
YearCount,
   FIRST_VALUE(T.FISCALYEAR) OVER(PARTITION BY T.ConstituentLookupID ORDER 
BY T.FISCALYEAR DESC) - T.FISCALYEAR + 1 as X,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.ConstituentLookupID ORDER BY 
T.FISCALYEAR DESC) AS RN
FROM #Temp AS T)
SELECT CTE.ConstituentLookupID,
   CTE.FISCALYEAR,
   CTE.YearCount,
   CTE.X,
   CTE.RN,
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.YearCount >= 4 --Have at least 4 years of giving
AND CTE.X - CTE.RN = 1 --Some kind of way to calculate consecutive years. Doesnt account current year and gaps...;
```

Comment: What are your expected results here? What were the attempts you made (that didn't work)?

Comment: Edit to original post as I couldn't post in reply...

Comment: Thats exactly where we want it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no duplicates, you can use `lag()`:

```
select distinct customerid
from (
    select t.*, 
        lag(orderyear, 3) over(partition by customerid order by orderyear) oderyear3
    from mytable t
) t
where orderyear = orderyear3 + 3
```

A more conventional approach is to use some gaps-and-islands technique. This is convenient if you want the start and end of each series. Here, an island is a series of rows with "adjacent" order years, and you want islands that are at least 4 years long. We can identify the islands by comparing the order year against an incrementing sequence, then use aggregation:

```
select customerid, min(orderyear) firstorderyear, max(orderyear) lastorderyear
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customerid order by orderyear) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by customerid, orderyear - rn
having count(*) >= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no more than one row per customer and year, the simplest method is `lag()`:

```
select customerid, year
from (select t.*,
             lag(orderyear, 3) over (partition by customerid order by orderyear) as prev3_year
      from t
     ) t
where prev3_year = year - 3;
```

The idea is to look 3 years back.  If that year is year - 3, then there are four years in a row.  If your data can have duplicates, there are tweaks to the logic (they make the query more slightly more complicated).

This could return duplicates, so you might just want:

```
select distinct customerid
from (select t.*,
             lag(orderyear, 3) over (partition by customerid order by orderyear) as prev3_year
      from t
     ) t
where prev3_year = year - 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution using row number and group by

```
SELECT Max(z.customerid), 
       Count(z.grp) 
FROM   (SELECT customerid, 
               orderyear, 
               orderyear - Row_number() 
                             OVER ( 
                               ORDER BY customerid) AS Grp 
        FROM   mytable)z 
GROUP  BY z.grp 
HAVING Count(z.grp) = 4
```